# what is this angular error?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arguments

Just made a simple controller with some injection.

```
var SimpleProductListController = BaseController.extend({

    _notifications:null,
    _productsModel:null,

    init:function($scope,ProductsModel,$route){
    },    
    defineListeners:function(){
        this._super();            
    },
    destroy:function(){

    }
})
/...

SimpleProductListController.$inject = ['$scope','ProductsModel','$route'];
```

The console error points to this: 
[http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/ng/areq?p0=SimpleProductListController&p1=not%20aNaNunction%2C%20got%20undefined](http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.16/ng/areq?p0=SimpleProductListController&p1=not%20aNaNunction,%20got%20undefined)

```
Argument 'SimpleProductListController' is not aNaNunction, got undefined
```

How am I supposed to even debug this? I got batarang but it does nothing here.

Comment: What is `BaseController`? This code looks very ember-y, not so much angular-y.

Comment: Pretty much lifting from https://github.com/trochette/Angular-Design-Patterns-Best-Practices but how do you even debug angular? all the errors are meaningless

Comment: Angular's actually usually pretty easy to debug. Errors like this are usually injector-related. So - there is some dependency that needs your SimpleProductListController and your app can't find it anywhere. Maybe you are double declaring your module? eg: `var app = angular.module('myModule',[]); /*then somewhere else*/ var app = angular.module('myModule',[/*this second [] parameter will bulldoze/undefine your first module*/]);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically, Angular is saying that SimpleProductListController is undefined.

When I've gotten that error, it was because I created a controller and tried to inject it into my app but I did not load the file that defines that controller by adding the script tag to my index.html file.

Comment: That was it, but what a terrible error message. It is not syntactically correct, let alone readable or discernible. `Argument 'SimpleProductListController' is not aNaNunction, got undefined` It's an ngBonics

Comment: This is a terrible error description. But after 2 hours I found out I made a typo in the controller name. FML.